# python 3 solving the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, python-3.6, stop-words

iam trying to remove stop words from a csv file which contain arabic sentences but i am not sure i got many erorrs

my code

```
print(tokenized_docs_no_punctuation)
    stops = set(stopwords.words('arabic'))
    words=tokenized_docs_no_punctuation
    print([word for word in words if word not in stops])
```

and this is the error 
[image]

any idea or solution??

Comment: what does this have to do with pandas?

Comment: because tokenized_docs_no_punctuation came from pandas dataframe csv

Comment: Can you add the content of `stops` and `words` to your question?

Comment: sorry what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` is telling that you are trying to hash a `list` object. According to the code you posted in your question it seems that `set(stopwords.words('arabic'))` is causing the error because `set` function tries to hash arguments to find duplicates. Take a look at `stopwords.words('arabic')` output and make sure there is no `list` object in the output.

Comment: my code is reading csv file with pandas and then tokenize it to remove stop words so what i have to do

Comment: can you write the output of `stopwords.words('arabic')` here?

Comment: ['إذ', 'إذا', 'إذما', 'إذن', 'أف', 'أقل', 'أكثر', 'ألا', 'إلا', 'التي', 'الذي', 'الذين', 'اللاتي', 'اللائي', 'اللتان', 'اللتيا', 'اللتين', 'اللذان', 'اللذين', 'اللواتي', 'إلى', 'إليك', 'إليكم', 'إليكما', 'إليكن', 'أم', 'أما', 'أما', 'إما', 'أن', 'إن', 'إنا', 'أنا', 'أنت', 'أنتم', 'أنتما', 'أنتن', 'إنما', 'إنه', 'أنى', 'أنى', 'آه', 'آها', 'أو', 'أولاء', 'أولئك', 'أوه', 'آي', 'أي', 'أيها', 'إي', 'أين', 'أين', 'أينما', 'إيه', 'بخ', 'بس', 'بعد', 'بعض', 'بك', 'بكم', 'بكم', 'بكما', 'بكن', 'بل', 'بلى', 'بما', 'بماذا', 'بمن', 'بنا', 'به', 'بها', 'بهم', 'بهما',